# select element in JQuery

Tags: jquery

Hi would you please help how can i extract "Men" text in this case?

```
<div class="comwebstore-LeftNavBrowse-2">
    <ul class="linkList browseLadder">
       <li>
           <a href="example.com"> Men </a>
       </li>
       <ul class="linkList browseLadder">
         <li>
            <a href="example.com"> Full Logo T-Shirt </a>
         </li>
         <li>
            <a href="example.com"> Short Logo T-Shirt </a>
         </li>
         <li>
            <a href="example.com"> Grey Hoodie 1 Full Logo </a>
         </li>
         <li>
           <a href="example.com"> Grey Hoodie 2 Short Logo </a>
         </li>
         <li>
            <a href="example.com"> Women </a>
         </li>
         <li>
            <a href="example.com"> Accessories </a>
         </li>
       </ul>
     </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

I have tried

> jQuery('#mainContentWrapper #leftColumn #A #A-1
>   .com-amazon-webstore-LeftNavBrowse-2 > :first-child a').text();

but without succeed.
Thanks

Comment: By what criteria? Will it always be the first item?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your html:

```
alert($('.linkList > li:first a').text());
```

Comment: that's shows both  Men and "Full Logo T-shirt". it should only shows "Men". THanks

Comment: @thelinhbui try: `$('.comwebstore-LeftNavBrowse-2 ul:first > li:first a').text()`

Answer (score 0):

Check your selector...`<div class="comwebstore-LeftNavBrowse-2">` You have `comwebstore-LeftNavBrowse-2` class and you're using `.com-amazon-webstore-LeftNavBrowse-2`

Please dont use such a long selectors. This will reduce your selectors performance and it looks ugly. Just check what **Alex Ball** has suggested.

```
jQuery('#mainContentWrapper #leftColumn #A #A-1 .comwebstore-LeftNavBrowse-2 > :first-child a').text();
```